# chart.js dynamically set values of suggestedMin and suggestedMax based on values of array

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

**problem**

making the chart of few curves more readable - especially this light green, which in some places has the same value and is straight

[image]

**how to solve this problem**

Set min and max values of y axis iot make more space above and below curve.
This values may be set by this code:

```
public lineChartOptions:any = {            
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          id: 'SeriesA',
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 100
          }
        }]
    }
};
```

Chart.js makes it automatically to calc this min and max value, however in some places I would like to extend it (by setting suggestedMin and suggestedMax values). Values should be based on min value of array (reduced by 10%) and max value of array (enlarged by 10%).

**For such an example data I wold like to get min value of Y axis of 54, and max of 66**

```
public seriesA: Array<number> = [59.023, 59.023, 59.034, 59.034, 59.034, 59.039, 59.05, 59.061, 59.088, 59.104];
    
public minMaxSeries: Array<number> = [0, 0];

 ngOnInit(): void {
    // calc min and max value of array
    this.minMaxSeries[0] = this.seriesB.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return Math.min(prev, curr);
    });
    this.minMaxSeries[1] = this.seriesB.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return Math.max(prev, curr);
    });
  
    // set values of min and max to the nearest integer value depends on its positive and negative values
    if (this.minMaxSeries[0] >= 0) {
      this.minMaxSeries[0] = Math.ceil(this.minMaxSeries[0] - 0.1 * this.minMaxSeries[0]);
    } else {
      this.minMaxSeries[0] = Math.floor(this.minMaxSeries[0] + 0.1 * this.minMaxSeries[0]);
    }
    if (this.minMaxSeries[1] >= 0) {
      this.minMaxSeries[1] = Math.ceil(this.minMaxSeries[1] + 0.1 * this.minMaxSeries[1]);
    } else {
      this.minMaxSeries[1] = Math.floor(this.minMaxSeries[1] - 0.1 * this.minMaxSeries[1]);
    }
    console.log(this.minMaxSeries)
  }
```

**my code:**
[**Angular project**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-hjw4xn?file=app%2Fline-chart.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the values on minMaxSeries does not alter `lineChartOptions`. If you add `console.log(this.lineChartOptions);` at the end of `ngOnInit()`, you will see that `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` still have value zero.

To solve your problem, you should set the options directly on `lineChartOptions` as follows:

```
this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max;
```

The `ngOnInit()` method could be simplified as shown below.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = Math.floor(Math.min(...this.seriesB));
  this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = Math.ceil(Math.max(...this.seriesB));
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-myycpy?file=app%2Fline-chart.component.ts).

Comment: This works when data is initialized at the beginning of the component. In fact I obtained data from external database, in `ngOnInit` method I set value of Array of this.seriesA, seriesB and so on - and in such configuration it doesn't work

Comment: When I set values `this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = Math.floor(Math.min(...this.seriesB));` on console.log there is appropriate value, however it doesn't change value on y axes.

Comment: Did you take a look at the amended StackBlitz? Also maybe a better option would be to use ticks.min and ticks.max.

Comment: As a last attempt, you can get rid of `ngOnInit` and move the code inside the `constructor`. This makes sure, the `lineChartOptions` are fully featured when the charts gets created.

Comment: I think that I have such a problem that, values of Array is initialized also in ngOnInit method, like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-cpyoac?file=app%2Fline-chart.component.ts however in my project curves are displayed in proper way,

Comment: Oh, I have noticed that in such a case I have when I'm trying to present 12 different curves Chart.js make some arrangements considering min and max values automatically due to the fact that I would not be possible to see any difference, this values changes when I toggle legend and hide and show corresponding cuvre